Extension for Chrome that delivers the request Headers as a dictionary to use in Python requests
Before I used this pattern to make requests to a website:
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

response = requests.get("https://test.com/", headers=headers)

Now the site owners have requested that I always use the full headers the same when I open the website in my Chrome browser.
But getting value by value is complicated, is there an extension for Chrome that gives me the complete headers in a dictionary or something like that to more easily place as an object in Python?
